# Cannot read reading 'style.transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to make a simple analog clock for my first project but after trying so many times,
I cannot understand why my `style.transform` is undefined(?)as seen on my inspect element and the clock didn't move as I wanted.

here is my code

```
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
    const now = new Date();

    const seconds = now.getSeconds();
    const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
    secondHand.style.transform = 'rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)';

    const mins = now.getMinutes();
    const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) *6) + 90;
    minsHand.style.transform = 'rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)';

    const hour = now.getHours();
    const hourDegrees = ((hour / 60) * 360) + ((mins / 60) * 30) + 90;
    hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)';

}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);

setDate();
```

Comment: If you ```console.log(secondHand)``` does it return anything?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 where should i input the log function? before the setDate or after it?

Comment: should also post the html code

Comment: @yusufermanto at the start of the ```SetDate()``` function is fine. Right underneath ```const now = new Date();```

Comment: @MichaelTr7 it marked it as null and the error says
'jam.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at setDate (jam.js:11:16)
setDate @ jam.js:11
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ jam.js:24
jam.js:7 null'

Comment: @waiaan '
<script src="jam.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="outer-clock-face">
            <div class="marking marking-one"></div>
            <div class="marking marking-two"></div>
            <div class="marking marking-three"></div>
            <div class="marking marking-four"></div>
            <div class="inner-clock-face">
                <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
                <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
                <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>'

Comment: put script tag just before </body>

Comment: @waiaan tried it but the console error only said
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at setDate (jam.js:11:16)
    at jam.js:26:1**

Comment: i change the code to this :' <head> </head> <body> <div class="clock"> <div class="outer-clock-face"> <div class="marking marking-one"></div> <div class="marking marking-two"></div> <div class="marking marking-three"></div> <div class="marking marking-four"></div> <div class="inner-clock-face"> <div class="hand hour-hand"></div> <div class="hand min-hand"></div> <div class="hand second-hand"></div> </div> </div> </div> <script src="jam.js"></script></body>' and it works fine

Comment: it did not console error ,but also nothing showed on the web page

Comment: @waiaan I'm sorry i thought it was <body> but instead you said </body> i didn't see that
now that i've changed it it work as you said, Thank you very much.

Comment: add jsfiddle or your code repo link.

Comment: All three `transform` values are formatted incorrectly: `'rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)'` is supposed to be a template literal so wrap it in grave marks ``` not single quotes '